# C# how to prevent duplications while adding record using oledb

Tags: c#

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\H3.mdb";

            con.Open();
            String DDate = DDD.Text.ToString();

            String my_query = "INSERT INTO DailyReport(DDate)VALUES('" + DDate + "')";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_query, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfuly...!");
            if(count>0)

            con.Close();
```

Comment: You can check if the same value is present in DB.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options. You can limit adding of duplicates on the level of database with unique constraint.

Second option is to open a transaction, and in the context of the transaction make select, check if it is empty, and only then make insert.

Comment: my unique set is the date, this form will be adding 1 record daily. and i'm using a combo box to review by date.
i tried to find a code to prevent it, but i got nothing :( ..